# Attribute "xmlns:?" must be declared for elements type "beans"

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm trying to use `<context:component-scan base-package="">` and `<context:annotation-config/>`. My xml file is as following

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">
</beans>
```

But eclipse kept throwing Attributes "xmlns", and "xmlns:aop", "xmlns:context" and so on, must be declared for elements type "beans". How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a side issue, if you're new to Spring, go with Spring Boot and JavaConfig rather than XML, even though all the old tutorials use XML.

Answer (score 0):

add spring beans xsd schemaLocation

`<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">`